# Why all sub-paths of my website are 404 not found?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04

Recently I've configured my server (LAMP) and uploaded my website. The [home page](https://lamtakam.com/) works well, but all the rest pages return `404 not found`. I guess the problem is related to `.htaccess` file. Here is the `.htaccess` file which exists on the root:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# this doesn't work on some version of xampp
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html


Options -Indexes

<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Noted that the server OS is ubuntu 16.04. Any idea how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Most likely, the [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) option in httpd.conf for your site's directory is set to `None` (by default).  Because of this, the .htaccess file is being ignored.  Change it to `All` and it should work.

Comment: @drew010 Do you know where is `httpd.conf` located in ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I'd look around in `/etc/apache2` if this is a Debian/Ubuntu package installed version of Apache.

Comment: @drew010 [Apparently ubuntu doesn't have `httpd.conf`](https://askubuntu.com/a/652100/728682). Do you know the same file in ubuntu? I mean the file which contains `AllowOverride` option.

Comment: Just look for AllowOverride in the entire `/etc/apache2` tree.  Most likely it is in one of the `sites-enabled` files, 000-default.conf if you're using the default vhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1
</Files>
```

blocks all the .php files except index.php (which is your home page).

Comment: Well the same `.htaccess` file works well on the localhost.

Comment: If by `localhost` you also mean testing from the same machine that is hosting, that makes sense. Take those lines out of `.htaccess` on the new host and restart Apache and see if that fixes it.

Comment: According to some tests I figured out `.htaccess` file will be ignored by apache.

Comment: If `.htaccess` is in the right place then normally Apache will use it.